# Find values with 2 or more consecutive numeric characters (SQL)

Tags: sql-server

I have a column of values that sometimes have consecutive numbers, how can I get all values that are 2+ consecutive numeric characters?  For example:

```
value
-------
car1339
foo3bar9
there10yes
hellothere
```

What would the SQL statement be to get the following?

```
car1339
there10yes
```

Comment: ... Where value like '%[0-9][0-9]%'

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff277/1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE value LIKE '%[0-9][0-9]%' ;
```